# Can I filter tags when doing git fetch?

Tags: git

My team creates many branches and tags, making my git GUI very crowded. I updated my `upstream` remote configuration like the following and deleted all contents in the `refs/tags` and `refs/remotes/upstream` folder, then I did a `git fetch --all`.

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = git@github.com:...git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/upstream/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/my-*:refs/remotes/upstream/my-*
    fetch = +refs/tags/my-*:refs/tags/my-*
```

The branches are cleaned up, and only the branches I want are fetched. But **all** the tags are still fetched.

Maybe my `fetch` syntax for filtering tags is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

So, it looks like `--tag` is implicit. I need to add a `tagopt` to the configuration section.

```
    tagopt = --no-tags
```

And make sure you don't add `--tags` when you do fetch.